# Рамка вокруг строки QTextEdit

Tags: c++, qt, style

Есть форма на ней QTextEdit (ui->textEdit);
Нужно сделать рамку вокруг текущей строки (как в Visual Studio)

Никак не пойму как

есть вот такой вариант, но он не работает

```
void MainWindow::paintEvent ( QPaintEvent * event )
{
     QPainter painter;
     painter.begin( ui->textEdit->viewport() );

     QRect r = ui->textEdit->cursorRect();
     r.setX( 0 );
     r.setWidth( ui->textEdit->viewport()->width() );
     painter.fillRect( r, QBrush( Qt::blue ) );
}
```

Comment: Я в этом не очень хорошо разбираюсь, но нельзя ли то, что Вам нужно сделать при помощи StyleSheet? Если бы точнее  `hover`-а?

Comment: Нет объекта однозначно описывающего строку, а у объектов типа QTextBlock нет styleSheet

Comment: Так у Вас `QTextEdit` или `QTextBlock`? У `QTextEdit` есть StyleSheet

Comment: мне нужна рамка вокруг строки, а не вокруг текстового поля

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Пожалуйста:

```
class MyTextEdit: public QTextEdit
{
protected:
    void paintEvent(QPaintEvent* event) {
        QPainter painter(viewport());

        QRect r = cursorRect();
        r.setX(0);
        r.setWidth(viewport()->width());
        painter.fillRect(r, QBrush(Qt::yellow));

        QTextEdit::paintEvent(event);
    }
};
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Я так понимаю мне нужно использовать везде свой класс "MyTextEdit" вместо стандартного

Comment: Например. Можно создать eventFilter в MainWindow, перехватывать события перерисовки QTextEdit и рисовать свое -- хватит и перенести тот код. Но вариант с собственным классом мне нравится намного больше